# Copy & Delete Sheet based on cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy, spreadsheet

I have create the add button based on code below to add new sheet:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("6.1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("6")
With Sheets("6")
For Each c In .Range("C8:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
specifictext = "Insert"
        sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It works based on image below where the new sheet has been added follow value in cell from column C when I click the button.

[image]

Now there are two things I want:

1. If I click the button for second time, I want nothing to happen if the sheet based on name from column C already exist. Because right now, when I click the button, it will pop-up "Run-time error 1004: That name is already taken. Try a different one.
2. When I delete value "D1" which refer to cell C12, I want sheet D1 also be deleted when I click the button. and no effect to the cell the I delete the value.

Help if really appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some helper subs to achieve that:

This one adds a sheet if there is a value in the phases range and it does not yet exist - by using `existsSheet`-function

```vb
Public Sub addSheetsIfNotExists(wsSourceToCopy As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)

Dim newSheetName As String

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arrValidPhases, 1)
    newSheetName = arrValidPhases(i, 1)
    If newSheetName <> "" Then
        If existsSheet(newSheetName) = False Then
            With ThisWorkbook
                wsSourceToCopy.Copy after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = newSheetName
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Function existsSheet(SheetNameToCheck As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNameToCheck)
If Not ws Is Nothing Then existsSheet = True
End Function
```

This one removes a sheet if it isn't present in the phases-range:

```vb
Public Sub checkSheetsForPhase(wsStartToCheck As Worksheet, arrValidPhases As Variant)
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, fExists As Boolean
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Index > wsStartToCheck.Index Then
        fExists = False
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrValidPhases, 1)
            If ws.Name = arrValidPhases(i, 1) Then
                fExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If fExists = False Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

You will call these subs from your click event like this:

```vb
Public Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("6.1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("6")

Dim arrPhases As Variant

With sh2
    arrPhases = .Range("C8:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

addSheetsIfNotExists sh1, arrPhases
checkSheetsForPhase sh1, arrPhases

sh2.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. It really work just like what i want.

Comment: Hi @Ike i have a bit problem with the coding. I have have new tab after tab "6.1". Take example, the tab name is "7". What happen now, when I click the button, the code work fine, but it delete the tab "7". Can you assist on this?